# What will be the time complexity of list(dict.keys()) in python3

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I was solving an algorithm question using list(dict.keys()) it was taking a lot more time
than OrderedDict dict.popitem(0) I know it'll return generator type object we can traverse over it and get every element like range in list.

Comment: `dict.popitem(0)` does something entirely different than `list(dict.keys())`. Why are you surprised they are are taking different time?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Theoretically an equivalent operation in `dict` should have been `O(n)` and require shifting all records, but as an implementation detail `dict` just marks it as deleted and avoids it. Maybe that was his line of thought?

Comment: @Bharel `OrderedDict` is a linked list on top of a sparse array and serves to efficiently preserve ordering, so both practically and theoretically `pop` should not be O(n) – it's kind of the point. Even for a `dict`, while the operation may have the same complexity it should naively be far from the same performance. Sure that *may* still be the reasoning (since there is no need to be correct about these things), but since it is the only background to the actual runtime aspect – i.e. what the question is about – it seems better to *know* than to guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time complexity is `O(n)` as you create a new list made of all elements.

If you just want the first, I suggest you to `next(iter(dict))` or `next(iter(dict.items()))` which will bring you the first key or `(key, value)` pair respectively at `O(1)`.

You can catch `StopIteration` to make sure the dict isn't empty or return a default value from `next()`:

```
>>> def take_first(d):
...   return next(iter(d), None)
...
>>> take_first({"a": 1, "b": 2})
'a'
>>> take_first({})
>>> # (None)
```